# Passing a custom object in Java

Tags: java

I know this is probably pretty basic, and I'm ashamed for not knowing how to do this (and worse yet, being unsuccessful in searching for a solution).

How would I pass an object of type *thing* from A to C?

```
public class A extends B {

}

public class B {

    public class thing {

    }

}

public class C extends JFrame {

}
```

I have access to *thing* in A because I'm extending B, but I'm unable to extend B when using class C because I need to extend JFrame.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the vagueness. Class A has a collection of objects of type *thing* and I want to iterate through those objects in class C.

**EDIT 2**

And of course... the obvious choice. Make *thing* its own class... :(

Admitting shame for the sake of those who may also have an issue like this.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. Is thing declared static? What is your goal exactly. In particular what method of C are you trying to call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if it's an inner class - you probably shouldn't access it from the outside...

But, if you insist, you can try to do as follows:

```
public class A extends B {

}

public class B {

    public class thing {

    }

    private thing mything = new thing();
    public thing getThing(){
      return mything;
    }

}

public class C extends JFrame {
      A a = new A();
      Object thing = a.getThing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

accessing an inner class from the outside is generally a bad idea, but if you must i wold suggest looking at the delegate design pattern like in this article :

[delegate design pattern](http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatterns/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably trying to use multi-inheritance which is not possible in java!
you can use interfaces to  have 2 different behavior or Use some design patterns 
to achieve such a goal.

It's really unclear what you are trying to do.however see composite or factory-method patterns
i think it could help.